# Colorozing very dark textures in OpenGl

Tags: opengl, textures

I believe that when you apply a color to a textured object in OpenGL it multiplies the color of glColor and the color of the texture data to determine what color to actually draw.  This is all fine and good for light colored textures but it presents a problem for trying to colorize darker textures, because if you have a blackish texture and try and colorize it red, it still turns out the same shade of blackish.  Does anyone know of any hacks or techniques to significantly lighten the color of a dark texture when setting the glColor?

Answer (score 1):

The comportment you describe is the basic GL_MODULATE behaviour, that is a plain simple multiply.

Depending on what platform, or GL version, you have available, you could consider :

- use shaders, that will allow you to do pretty much any operation on your texture images
- use other, more complete, TexEnv modes to replace GL_MODULATE ; I don't know for sure which would suit you, but with enough creativity maybe [one of those](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexEnv.xml) could suit you. I think I remember there were plenty of extensions around TexEnv, that may be useful too.

Answer (score 0):

Brighten the texture first, then colorize as usual.

To brighten the texture, two basic techniques are:

- Additive brightening: Add a constant value to every texel.
- Multiplicative brightening: Multiply every texel by a value larger than 1. E.g. multiply everything by 1.1 for +10% brightness.

Answer (score 0):

Gamma correction may play a role here. Lighting black with red is still black, that is as intended. However, if "darkish" (non-black) things still appear "mostly black" then this suggests that something goes wrong.

Images, including textures, are often saved as sRGB, because most people have their monitor set up that way anyway, and therefore this looks best for most people when displayed on-screen. Unluckily, that is no longer true if you do math with the values!

If EXT_texture_sRGB is supported (core in version 2.1), you should try using the respective "S" constant when loading the texture. Otherwise, you can do the math by hand in a shader, too.

=====> [useful gamma literature](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch24.html)